# New to emacs -- my key bindings are different from what is described in the tutorials. How to fix this?

Tags: shortcut-keys, mouse, kde, emacs

I'm using emacs v24 [GNU Emacs 24.0.94.1 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, GTK+ Version 3.3.20)
 of 2012-03-26 on meitnerium, modified by Debian] on Kubuntu 12.04.

My basic problem is that emacs is not behaving the same as the tutorials I'm reading. I either need different tutorials or I need to make my emacs work as described in the tutorials. Being new to emacs and KDE, I don't know where to start because of this incongruence.

My specific problem is this:

When I shift-left-mouse-click, I get a **buffer dialog popup**. That differs from my understanding of the documenation:

> shift mouse-1  Draws lines, rectangles or poly-lines, erases, cuts, copies or pastes.

I also want to use CUA mode. The [CUA mode documents](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/RectangleMark) seem to indicate that shift-left-mouse-click produces:

> rectangle highlighting by dragging the mouse while holding down the shift key.

I don't get that result either. In fact, I can't select using any modifier keys together with a drag action. Maybe this is a KDE issue. I don't know.

Comment: Do you have a `.emacs`? Press `f1`, `c`, then Shift+left button: this should display “<S-down-mouse-1> at that spot runs the command …” in the mode line, what does it display (you can copy-paste from the `*Messages*` buffer)?

Comment: I do not have a .emacs file. What is the F1 key supposed to do? It is globally bound to KDE stuff, so the F1 keystroke never reaches emacs.

Comment: If C-h is the same as F1, then this is probably what you are looking for: "<S-down-mouse-1> at that spot runs the command mouse-appearance-menu". What next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Shift`+`MouseLeft` runs the command `mouse-appearance-menu` by default since Emacs 23 (before, it ran `mouse-set-font`). This is the buffer dialog popup that you saw.

You can find out what a key (or key combination) or mouse button does in your Emacs by pressing `C-h c` (i.e. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> then <kbd>C</kbd>) then the key(s) or button. The name of the command that it invokes will appear at the bottom of the screen. If you press `C-h k`, you will also see the documentation of that command. Conversely, if you happen to know the name of a command and want to know what key invokes it, press `C-h w` then enter the name of the command. You can use `f1` instead of `C-h`.

You didn't say what tutorial you were using. I suspect you missed something in your reading. The text “shift mouse-1 Draws lines, rectangles or poly-lines, erases, cuts, copies or pastes” appears in the documentation of [Artist Mode](http://emacswiki.org/emacs/ArtistMode), an Emacs package (included in the standard Emacs distribution) that facilitates drawing ASCII pictures. To enter Artist Mode, type `M-x artist-mode RET` (i.e. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd>, then type `artist-mode` and <kbd>Return</kbd>).